# serial port on vmware has overlapping error

Tags: virtual-machine, serial

I have a VMware and a card reader with USB as serial port . I want to forward a serial port on my windows( 8.1) to VMware (Ubuntu). But It shows me this error:
[image]
How can I use my com port on VMware.

Comment: Just to clarify: if I understand correctly you have one physical machine, running Windows 8.1, you have installed VMware, and in VMWare you have started a VM running Ubuntu, is that correct?

Comment: yes. i installed vmware on windows 8.1. then install ubuntu on vmware. then i want to forward my serial port on windows to ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved Problem: when I create the new serial port that overlap the serial port. when I deleted new serial port, that error not occurred.